# Microsoft ODBC Driver for Oracle vs Oracle 12.1 ODBC Driver for COM ADO

Tags: c++, oracle, com, odbc, ado

We're switching from Microsoft ODBC Driver for Oracle (on Server 2012 R2) to Oracle 12c (12.1) ODBC Driver, in use over old-school COM C++ assemblies.

We're using msado15.dll for these calls.  Our stored procedures that used to return out parameters ie.

```
// Instantiation
_ConnectionPtr  m_spConnection;
_CommandPtr     spCmd(__uuidof(Command));
_ParameterPtr   spParam(__uuidof(Parameter));
_variant_t      vHold;

spCmd->CommandText = "MyPackage.MyProcedure";
spCmd->CommandType = adCmdStoredProc;

spParam = spCmd->CreateParameter("my_input_param", adDouble, adParamInput, 0, 0);
spCmd->Parameters->Append(spParam);
spParam = NULL;
spParam = spCmd->CreateParameter("my_output_param", adDouble, adParamOutput, 0, 0);
spCmd->Parameters->Append(spParam);
spParam = NULL;

// Call the Proc
spCmd->PutRefActiveConnection(m_spConnection);
try
{
    spCmd->Execute(NULL, NULL, adCmdStoredProc);
}
catch (const _com_error &err)
{
    // We do not get an error here.
    hrRetval = err.Error();
    printf(err.Description());
}
catch (...)
{
    // Nor do we get an error here.
    printf("Error!");
}

vHold = spCmd->Parameters->GetItem("my_output_param")->GetValue();

if (vHold.dblVal <= 0)
{
    printf("I should not get here, but I do!");
}
```

no longer return us the expected values.  We get 0 back, and we shouldn't.

This all worked fine on Server 2008 with Microsoft ODBC Oracle driver, but the move to Server 2012 R2 necessitated us move to Oracle's ODBC driver.  This seems to be our biggest hurdle - hoping someone out there has tackled this previously :)

Did some ODBC tracing as well:

```
MyApp      14c8-a5c ENTER SQLExecDirectW 
    HSTMT               0x09662B08
    WCHAR *             0x1A5C13F0 [      -3] "{ call MyPackage.MyProcedure(?, ?) }\ 0"
    SDWORD                    -3

MyApp      14c8-a5c EXIT  SQLExecDirectW  with return code 0 (SQL_SUCCESS)
    HSTMT               0x09662B08
    WCHAR *             0x1A5C13F0 [      -3] "{ call MyPackage.MyProcedure(?, ?) }\ 0"
    SDWORD                    -3

MyApp      14c8-a5c ENTER SQLGetDiagFieldW 
    SQLSMALLINT                  3 
    SQLHANDLE           0x09662B08
    SQLSMALLINT                  0 
    SQLSMALLINT              -1249 
    SQLPOINTER         0x001897B0
    SQLSMALLINT                  4 
    SQLSMALLINT *       0x00000000

MyApp      14c8-a5c EXIT  SQLGetDiagFieldW  with return code 100 (SQL_NO_DATA_FOUND)
    SQLSMALLINT                  3 
    SQLHANDLE           0x09662B08
    SQLSMALLINT                  0 
    SQLSMALLINT              -1249 
    SQLPOINTER         0x001897B0
    SQLSMALLINT                  4 
    SQLSMALLINT *       0x00000000
```

Running the proc in TOAD returns the expected data.

Thanks!

Comment: This is a wild guess, but try replacing the ODBC call function with:  "BEGIN MyPackage.MyProcedure(?, ?); END;"  and see if that works.

Comment: Please post the SQL command not just the parameters.

Comment: I've added the instantiation of all associated objects + sample usage.